# Unknown authorization header when using java gdata sdk

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Lately, we are hitting about 30% failed API calls in our regression tests, caused by "Unknown authorization header" exception.
We are getting the following exception from gdata java sdk:

```
Caused By AuthenticationException:

com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Unknown authorization header
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unknown authorization header</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unknown authorization header</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:600)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:631)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
```

We are running our regression tests using gdata api, using over 20 JVM for each test case.
This error is new. It emerged without changing our implementation, nor a significant change in load.
However, the error rate changes accordingly as we change the number concurrent JVMs, dropping to about 10% error rate as we reduce the number of JVMs to a few ones.

We would appreciate any help regarding the cause of the error and possible fixes.

Thanks
Assaf

Comment: Can you post the relevant code where you're setting up the Auth calls?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private DocsService getDocsService(boolean withHeader) {

    DocsService docsService = new DocsService(APP_NAME);

    try {

        docsService.setOAuthCredentials(getAuthParameters(),
                new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());

        if (withHeader) {
            docsService.getRequestFactory().setHeader("If-Match", "*");
        }

        return docsService;

    } catch (OAuthException oAuthException) {

        throw new TestFlowException(
                "Failed to set Google Drive Oauth Credentials",
                oAuthException);
    }

}

private GoogleOAuthParameters getAuthParameters() {

    GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();

    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(GOOGLE_DRIVE_KEY.getKey());
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(GOOGLE_DRIVE_KEY.getSecret());
    oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(ACCESS_CREDENTIALS.getKey());
    oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(ACCESS_CREDENTIALS.getPassword());

    return oauthParameters;
}
```